# How to manipulate css code line by time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is, how to manipulate this line in css by time with like a javascript code, for an other image? Like a slideshow!

If it's only possible in that way, in another code language.

```
.header { background: url(../img.jpg); }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function to do it:

```
$(".header").css("background", "../img/bg2.jpg");
```

Comment: its same solution like my

Answer (score -1):

You have to add background property into style attribute. because you have no chance go to css file via js